# How to delete the first node in a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I know this is a silly question, but I'm having a hard time deleting the first node in a linked list, even though the algorithm works when it's not the first node.

```
public boolean eliminarInscripcion(int DNI)
{
    boolean flag=false;
    Nodo aux, aux2;        //Nodo=Node

    if(Raiz!=null) //If the list isn't empty
    {
        aux=Raiz;  //Raiz=Root
        if(aux.getInfo().getDni() == DNI)  //Is the first node the one i'm looking for?
        {
            aux.setProx(aux.getProx()); //Here is the main problem. (I've tried many things, this is one of them, looks silly anyway.)
            flag=true;
        }
        else
        {
            aux2=aux.getProx();  //getProx=getNext
            while(aux.getProx()!=null)
            {
                if (aux2.getInfo().getDni()==DNI)
                {
                    aux.setProx(aux2.getProx());
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    aux=aux.getProx();
                    aux2=aux2.getProx();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return flag;   
}
```

Oh, and thank you very much!

Edit: I'll add some more information: the List class only has 1 atribute that is a Nodo (Raiz), the nodo class is this one:

```
public class Nodo
{
private Inscripcion Info;
private Nodo Prox;

public Nodo()
{
    Info = null;
    Prox = null;
}

public Nodo(Inscripcion info, Nodo prox)
{
    this.Info = new Inscripcion(info);
    this.Prox = prox;
}

public Inscripcion getInfo() 
{
    return Info;
}

public void setInfo(Inscripcion I) 
{
    this.Info = new Inscripcion(I);
}

public Nodo getProx() 
{
    return Prox;
}

public void setProx(Nodo P) 
{
    this.Prox = P;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return Info.toString();
}
```

}

Inscripcion is another class with a lot of data, I don't think itt's going to be useful here.

Comment: How is the `Nodo` class implemented?

Comment: What's happening that you're not expecting? Is it not deleting? Throwing an error?

Comment: `aux.setProx(aux.getProx());` looks like a no-op. I can't see the definition of `getProx`, but did't you mean `aux.setProx(aux.getProx().getProx());`?

Comment: It is not deleting the node, I dont get any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
if(aux.getInfo().getDni() == DNI)
        {
            Raiz=aux.getProx();
            flag=true;
        }
```

That's how I delete the first node in my list!, thanks everybody for your questions/answers!

Answer (score 2):

In a linked list, you have have a pointer to the first node and a pointer to the last node. You would do the following in (pseudo code)

```
LinkedList list = myList
Node node = list.head // get head
list.head = node.next // set new head to the second node in the list
node.next = null // remove the reference to the next node from the old head
```

You might also have to reassign the tail.

If you post your linked list class, we can help you further.

Comment: What purpose is resetting `node.next`? I've never done it and I'm still alive.

Comment: You might be keeping a reference to that node, but not to the one it's referencing, in which case it won't be GC'ed. Edge case really.

Comment: IOW not really worth it `:-)`?

Comment: Note that one particular Java class _doesn't_ destroy the nodes, and refuses to do for a purpose (to provide thread-safe iterators): `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Comment: So you return your internal data structures, but you mutilate them first so that they cannot betray you? Why does that seem like a bad design?

Comment: Actually, you are correct, you wouldn't return the node, but the element in the node.

Comment: Why would I have to reassign the tail if the part of the list I'm editing is the head?

Comment: If you only have one element and you remove it, the tail is still pointing to it so you might have weird behavior. You want the tail to be up to date just like the head.